# AttributeError: Rectangle instance has no attribute 'y'

Tags: python, attributes

I am coding a program in which a user draws a rectangle, and then the perimeter and area are calculated. In finding the lengths of two sides, I get an `AttributeError: Rectangle instance has no attribute 'y'`.

Here is my code so far:

```
from graphics import*

win=GraphWin('Rectangle',800,800)

def twopoints():
    pRight=win.getMouse()
    pRight.draw(win)
    pLeft=win.getMouse()
    pLeft.draw(win)
    print (pLeft)
    print (pRight)

    rec=Rectangle(pRight,pLeft)
    rec.draw(win)
    rec.setFill('red')
    return pRight, pLeft, rec

p1=Point(400, 100) 
m=Text(p1,"Click two places on the screen to create a rectangle")
m2=Text(Point(400, 150), "Your first click will be the upper right corner")
m3=Text(Point(400, 200), "Your second click will be the bottom left corner")
m.draw(win)
m2.draw(win)
m3.draw(win)

rec, pRight, pLeft=twopoints()

m.setText("Click to get either the area or perimeter")
m2.undraw()
m3.undraw()

side1=abs(pLeft.y-pRight.y)
side2=abs(pLeft.x-pRight.x)
print (side1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order you return multiple things in is important. Here, you

```
return pRight, pLeft, rec
```

But then assign it to

```
rec, pRight, pLeft=twopoints()
```

Python doesn't  match these by name here, only by order,  so `pLeft` outside is actually the same as `rec` inside.